Can you set ./server.ts itself as an entry point for the SSR build?
I scaffolded a new vite project using pnpm create vite. To make this reproducible, these were my choices when prompted:

Select a framework: Others
Select a variant: create-vite-extra
Select a template: ssr-vue
Select a variant: Non-streaming
Select a variant: TypeScript

I wanted to use TypeScript for the generated ./server.js, and not only the code in ./src, so I "converted" (i.e. renamed for now) server.js to server.ts.
At this point I realized I'd have to build ./server.ts myself, and have vite build the so called server side entry point ./src/entry-server.ts.
I'm using vite to avoid the nightmare of having to configure building TypeScript, so I'm wondering if it's feasible to set ./server.ts itself as an entry point for the SSR build? That, and still have SSR working.
The part where I'm stuck is how to actually import ./src/entry-server.ts, now that ./server.ts is my entry point (i.e. render = (await import('./dist/server/entry-server.js')).render doesn't work anymore now that entry-server.js is no longer getting built).

I got this working. Here's what I did, in case it's useful to someone else.
./src/server.ts is the vite ssr entry point and the script that node runs to start an express server. See package.json further down to see how it's run.
import express from 'express'
import { ViteDevServer } from 'vite'

import { ssr } from '@/ssr'

const PORT = process.env.PORT && parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 5173
const STATIC_URL = process.env.STATIC_URL || '/static/'
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'prod'
 
async function createServer() {
  let vite: ViteDevServer | undefined

  const app = express()
  
  if (isProd) {
    // Serve static files.
    app.use(STATIC_URL, express.static('./dist/client')) 
  } else {
    // Add vite middleware for static file serving, dev ssr, and hmr.
    const { createServer } = await import('vite')
    vite = await createServer({
      server: { middlewareMode: true },
      appType: 'custom',
      base: STATIC_URL
    })
    app.use(vite.middlewares)      
  }

  // Serve HTML
  app.use('', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      // TODO: Validate pageName and props.
      const url = req.originalUrl
      const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(
        Object.entries(req.query).map(([key, value]) => [key, String(value)])
      )
      const pageName = queryParams.get('page')
      if (!pageName) {
        res.status(400).send('A page name is required.')
        return
      }
      // TODO: Get props from request.
      const props = { msg: 'Hello from SSR!' }

      // Render the page.
      const html = await ssr(pageName, props, url, vite)

      res.status(200).set({ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }).send(html)
    } catch (e) {
      const err = e as Error
      console.log(err)
      res.status(500).end(err.stack)
    }
  })

  return app
}

createServer().then((app) => {
  app.listen(PORT, '127.0.0.1', () => {
    console.log(`Server started at http://127.0.0.1:${PORT}`)
  })
}).catch((err: Error) => {
  logger.error(err)
})


./src/ssr.ts uses import.meta.glob to preload components in prod (but a dynamic import like '(await import(./pages/${pageName}.vue)).default' would also work). ssr.ts also caches index.html in prod, but reloads it on each request in dev.
./src/ssr.ts
import fs from 'node:fs/promises'
import path from 'path'

import { ViteDevServer } from 'vite'
import { Component, createSSRApp } from 'vue'
import { renderToString } from 'vue/server-renderer'

export const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'prod'

const __dirname = import.meta.dirname

// loadIndexHtml loads and caches index html in prod.
// It always reloads the html in dev.
let indexHtmlCache: string = ''
async function loadIndexHtml(originalUrl: string, vite?: ViteDevServer) {
  if (isProd && indexHtmlCache === '') {
    indexHtmlCache = await fs.readFile('./dist/client/index.html', 'utf-8')
  } else if (vite) {
    indexHtmlCache = await fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8')
    indexHtmlCache = await vite.transformIndexHtml(originalUrl, indexHtmlCache)
  }
  if (indexHtmlCache === '') {
    throw Error("Failed to load index html.")
  }
  return indexHtmlCache
}

export async function ssr(
  pageName: string, 
  props: any, 
  originalUrl: string,
  vite?: ViteDevServer
) {
  let page: Component | undefined = undefined

  if (!isProd && !vite) {
    throw Error("The vite parameter wasn't provided but is required in dev.")
  }

  const indexHtml = await loadIndexHtml(originalUrl, vite)

  // Load page component.
  if (isProd) {
    const pages: Record<string, { default: Component }> = import.meta.glob(
      './pages/*.vue', { eager: true, import: 'default' }
    )
    page = pages[`./pages/${pageName}.vue`]
  } else if (vite) {
    page = (await vite.ssrLoadModule(
      path.resolve(__dirname, `./pages/${pageName}.vue`), { fixStacktrace: true }
    )).default
  }
  if (!page) {
    throw new Error(`Page "${pageName}" not found.`)
  }

  // SSR render the page component and embed it into the index html.
  const app = createSSRApp(page, props)
  const pageHtml = await renderToString(app)
  const html = indexHtml!
        .replace(`<!--page-html-->`, pageHtml ?? '')
        .replace(`<!--page-name-->`, `window.__PAGE_NAME__ = '${pageName}'`)
        .replace(`<!--initial-state-->`, `window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(props)}`)

  return html
}


./vite.config.ts
import path from 'path'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

const PORT = process.env.PORT && parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 5173
const STATIC_URL = process.env.STATIC_URL || '/static/'

const __dirname = import.meta.dirname

export default defineConfig((config) => {
  const buildTarget = process.env.BUILD_TARGET

  // Common configuration used for both dev and building.
  const baseConfig = {
    plugins: [vue()],
    base: STATIC_URL,
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
      }
    },
    server: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: PORT,
      hmr: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
      },
    },
  }

  // Build-specific options
  if (buildTarget === 'client') {
    return {
      ...baseConfig,
      build: {
        outDir: 'dist/client'
      }
    }
  } else if (buildTarget === 'server') {
    return {
      ...baseConfig,
      publicDir: false,
      build: {
        ssr: 'src/server.ts',
        outDir: 'dist/server',
      },
    }
  } else {
    return baseConfig
  }
})

package.json scripts section:
  "scripts": {
    "build:client": "BUILD_TARGET=client vite build",
    "build:server": "BUILD_TARGET=server vite build",
    "build": "pnpm build:client && pnpm build:server",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec tsx src/server.ts --watch . --ignore dist --ignore logs --ignore node_modules",
    "prod": "pnpm build && NODE_ENV=prod node dist/server/server.js"
  },

